# Matrix Multiplication

Tags: microsoft-excel

See screenshot of Excel operation

[image: See screenshot of Excel operation]

Is there a simpler way to perform this operation as seen in screenshot?

Distributive multiplication for multiple columns that is then summed together. Is there an excel formula similar to MMULT or SUMPRODUCT that can perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `SUMPRODUCT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J16</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D16:H16*D5:H14)
```

---

Or, If you are using `MS365` then simply use `SUM()`

```
=SUM(D16:H16*D5:H14)
```

---

Or, Using `MMULT()` however using the `SUM()` or `SUMPRODUCT()` is suffice. Also note if you are not using `MS365` change the `TOCOL()` to `TRANSPOSE()`

```
=SUM(MMULT(D5:H14,TOCOL(D16:H16)))
```

---